# Multiple network graph in single plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, seaborn

I am trying to plot 2 network graphs in the same plot. I have use the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['A','A','A','A'], 'to':['D', 'A', 'E','C']})
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'from', 'to')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':['S','S','S','S'], 'to':['L', 'K', 'M','N']})
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df1, 'from', 'to')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The problem is both of them overlap,and thus only 1 graph is visible. How do I create space between these graphs, so that both of them are visible clearly?

Thanks

Comment: Try using subplots as in this tutorial: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/examples/drawing/four_grids.html?highlight=subplot

Comment: @VictorValente It worked...!! Thanks